# Writing forms in django generates duplicated rows when using save() method

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views, django-crispy-forms

I'm building a form based on different models using django and I was struggling because I was generating duplicates rows and I fixed it with the code below but I'm interested in hearing suggestions to write this code better:

```
#views.py 
def make_customer(request, id):
    # Get the customer object or return a 404 response if it doesn't exist
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=id)
    print(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        address_form = AddressForm(request.POST)
        company_form = CompanyForm(request.POST)


        if contact_form.is_valid() and address_form.is_valid() and company_form.is_valid():


            if customer.company:  # Update existing company, contact, and address
                company = customer.company
                print(company_form.cleaned_data)
                company.name = company_form.cleaned_data['name']
                company.customer_information_file_number = company_form.cleaned_data['customer_information_file_number']
                company.contact.name = contact_form.cleaned_data['name']
                company.contact.email = contact_form.cleaned_data['email']
                company.contact.cc_email = contact_form.cleaned_data['cc_email']
                company.address.street = address_form.cleaned_data['street']
                company.address.city = address_form.cleaned_data['city']
                company.address.postal_code = address_form.cleaned_data['postal_code']

                company.contact.save()
                company.address.save()
                company.save()
            else:  # Create a new company if it doesn't exist
                contact = contact_form.save()
                address = address_form.save()
                company = Company.objects.create(
                    name=company_form.cleaned_data['name'],
                    customer_information_file_number=company_form.cleaned_data['customer_information_file_number'],
                    contact=contact,
                    address=address
                )
                customer.company = company
                customer.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Customer saved successfully')

            return redirect('view_customers')

    else:  # GET request
        contact_form = ContactForm(
            instance=customer.company.contact) if customer.company else ContactForm()
        address_form = AddressForm(
            instance=customer.company.address) if customer.company else AddressForm()
        company_form = CompanyForm(
            instance=customer.company) if customer.company else CompanyForm()

    context = {
        'contact_form': contact_form,
        'address_form': address_form,
        'company_form': company_form,
    }

    return render(request, 'invoices/form_customer.html', context)
```

This is the forms file:

```
#forms.py
class ContactForm(ModelForm):
    prefix = 'contact'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column(
                    'name', css_class='form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 mb-0'),
                Column(
                    'email', css_class='form-group col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb-0'),
                Column(
                    'cc_email', css_class='form-group col-lg-12 col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb-0'),
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'cc_email']


class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    prefix = 'address'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column(
                    'street', css_class='form-group col-lg-6 col-md-3 col-sm-5 mb-0'),
                Column(
                    'postal_code', css_class='form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb-0'),
                Column(
                    'city', css_class='form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb-0'),
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Address
        fields = ['city', 'postal_code', 'street']


class CompanyForm(ModelForm):
    prefix = 'company'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customer_information_file_number'].label = 'CIF'
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(
                Column(
                    'name', css_class='form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 mb-0'),
                Column(
                    'customer_information_file_number', css_class='form-group col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-3 mb-0'),
            )
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['name', 'customer_information_file_number']
```

I was using `contact_form.save()` but I was duplicating the rows each time I saved the form. I changed it to `contact_form.cleaned_data['cc_email']` and using this is not duplicating the row but I thing it should be a way to use the .save() function to get the same behaviour. Any help on this please?